# ¿Por qué no funciona este código php?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Lo que quiero es que limite el número de posts que mi usuario puede tener, pero no funciona, siempre me dice que tengo demasiados, estoy probando con un cuenta que tiene dos, y me redirige al else, o sea, me dice que tengo demasiados. ¿Me ayudan a ver cual es mi problema? gracias.

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){

 $sql2 = ("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE creador = '$user'");
 $q = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
 if( !mysqli_num_rows($q) >= 3){
  $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
  $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
  $date = date('Y/m/d');
  $sql = ("INSERT INTO posts VALUES('$user','$titulo','$mensaje','$date', '0', '0', '')");
  mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  header("Location: home.php?add=0");
 }else{
  header("Location: home.php?add=12");

 }
}
```

Comment: Elimina los parentesis de las consultas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema parece estar en la condicional del if:

if( !mysqli_num_rows($q) >= 3){

La función mysqli_num_rows te devuelve el número de resultados. En esta condicional se evalúa la función y se niega. Si el resultado es un valor distinto de 0, entonces la negación es 0. Luego se evalúa si 0 es mayor o igual que 3, cosa que es falsa.

Por ello, tu código pasa por el Else en cuanto el usuario tiene un número de comentarios mayor que 0.

SOLUCIÓN

Cambia tu condicional con parentesis, cambiando de posición la negación:

if( !(mysqli_num_rows($q) >= 3)){

De esta manera primero evalúas el número de resultados mayor o igual que 3, y si es distinto, entrará en la primera parte del if. En caso de ser igual a 3, la condición será falsa y pasará por el else

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó